# How to generate public key from private key and authenticate a request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am creating a NodeJs application and there will be only one client of this NodeJS application, there are no such requirements for login/register, etc. I just wanted to protect APIs using the JWT token.

Comment: You don't generate a public key from a private key.  You generate them both at once as a pair and store them.  There is a particular mathematical relationship between the public key and private key (that allows them to be used for security) and one cannot be derived from the other.

Comment: Then how can I validate my public key using secret key?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  "Protect APIs" is very vague and non-specific. https (which uses public/private key pairs internally) can be used to protect APIs.   A username and "password secret" can be used to protect APIs.  And, so on...

Comment: I think I've found a solution, I am trying to implement JWT authentication without any database, login, etc.
Helpful resource: https://auth0.com/learn/token-based-authentication-made-easy/

Answer (score 0):

What they say is not absolutely true. Of course you can fetch a private key and by using a math algorithm get then the public key. That is the case in ethereum for example. You can peak almost any 256 bit private key, then you apply the ecdsa algorithm and you will get the public key. When using other algorithms like RSA this won't work, as they say, you generate the pair. The thing with ecdsa is that you can easly get to the public key by doing some calculations but in order to go to the other way you will have to try using brute force and of course that if your private key is too strong that would be almost imposible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).